Was Yehonatan a mored b'malchut?
In Shmuel 19:1 Shaul, the king, clearly gives instructions to kill David, which he reinforces even after swearing not to kill David (v.6) by sending soldiers to kill David and even going himself to do so. David says as much to Yehonatan in 20:1 and Shaul reiterates in 20:31 such that finally in v.33 Yehonatan himself concludes that Shaul is in fact trying to kill David.
My question is, since Shaul is still the king of the Jews, and has made it clear that he wishes to kill David, is it a rebellion against the king for Yehonatan to then assist David or prevent Shaul from killing David? Meaning, would Yehonatan be halachically guilty of a capital offense such that any court (or perhaps anyone) could rightfully kill him?

One is not obligated -or allowed- to obey the king if his decree is against the Torah. (This is why Saul's servants refused to kill the priests of Nov.) As David was innocent, Saul's command did not have any halachic validity.

Innocent of what? The halachik threshold for being mored b'malchut is vague and minimal. For example chazal say Uriah was mored for calling Yoav his master. Couldn't Shaul likewise find a reason that David was a mored, like his not coming to the Rosh chodesh meal?

Shaul himself admitted later on that he had no reason to be upset at David. And he was under no specific command to go to the meal. From context it seems like it was normal to ask permission from Yonasan if one did not want to go.

that's not what Shaul says at the meal

@rikitikitembo https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.24.18?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he
